# Runing a command without inheriting parent's environment

Tags: bash, shell, session

Is there a way to run a command "as if" it is in a new login session?

I've already tried `env -i`. However, I don't want to deal with various ENV variables I have to set or unset.

I've also tried `bash -c "some command"` and `bash -l -c "some commmand"`, but they all copy the current environment.

The closest I have come is a not-so-clean solution:

```
ssh me@localhost "some command"`
```

Comment: Use `/bin/bash --login` to get that behavior. I use it e.g. to get a proper `$PATH`.

Comment: That is the equivalent of `/bin/bash --l`, which I already tried.   It copies the original environment. Try it: `export SOME_VAL=something`. Then `/bin/bash --login`. Then `env | grep SOME_VAL`. The value will be there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an answer that doesn't require sudo privileges or the user's password, but still provides an environment like what you'd get on a fresh login.

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'your_command'
```

Example:

```
$ export ABC=123
$ env -i HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'env' | grep ABC
$ env HOME="$HOME" bash -l -c 'env' | grep ABC
ABC=123
```

Breaking this down for explanation:

1. `env -i HOME="$HOME"`: Clears the environment. The `-i` sets up an empty environment with *no variables whatsoever*. This is problematic because it means that if you try to naively run `bash -l` it won't load your `.bash_profile` etc. because `HOME` isn't set. To mitigate this, we explicitly pass `HOME="$HOME"`, creating an environment where `HOME` (and only `HOME`) is set.
2. `bash -l -c ...`: Runs the desired command in a login shell. You'll want a login shell for this because we're starting from a clean environment and need to reload everything.

Notably:

- This doesn't require sudo privileges (the `sudo` version does).
- This doesn't require typing the user's password (the `su` version does).
- This doesn't require running an SSH server and having a passwordless key that can be used to log back in to the machine (the `ssh` version does).

Answer (score 15):

```
su -l $USER

sudo -u $USER -i
```

For something even more aggressive try `env -i bash`, but that unsets *everything* including $HOME and $TERM.

Comment: Thanks! The second command gives me exactly what I want. I searched for more than 2 hours and did not find anything close to your reply.  Based on your reply, I went back to `man sudo` and found: "if the target user is the same as the invoking user, no password is required."   (The `su` seems to always asks for a password.)  I'm such a fool to have overlooked something so simple in the first paragraph of a `man` page :(  I avoided sudo in the first place because I assumed it always asked for a password. Thanks again!

Comment: just a hint for others... if your logged in as `$USER` you will need to login as root and then `sudo -u ...` as your user. If you just do `sudo -u` as the user you will inherit.

Comment: this does not work, obviously, if you do not have `sudo` access. Is there an alternative method that does not require sudo?

Comment: @user5359531: Yes – `su -l $USER`.

Comment: that asks for a password; I am logged in via ssh key authentication, so I dont even know what the password is. And a password prompt is going to kill script-ability. So far its looking like `ssh $USER@localhost <command>` is working better

Comment: @grawity Do you have a better answer to user5359531's question?

Comment: @Melab: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1333539/143224).